# R extracting members of lists and sub-lists (S4 class)

Tags: r, list, extract, r-s4, members

I am struggling with extracting members from lists. The code shown below produces a list of 5 members with each member having a (sub)list of two members. 
I would like to extract the first members of each sub-list i.e (W1  and V1). How do I do this?

```
library(wavelets)

library(fGarch)

x<-rnorm(32)

spec.c <- garchSpec(model = list(omega=0.99, alpha=0.005, beta=0.005))

sim <- replicate(5, dwt(cumsum(garchSim(spec.c, n = 32)), filter="haar", 
                                    n.levels=2, boundary="reflection"))
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
W <- lapply( sim , function(x) `@`( x , W)[[1]] )
V <- lapply( sim , function(x) `@`( x , V)[[1]] )
```

You'll get a list of the first `W` of each of the 5 top-level lists and the first `V` of each of the 5 top-level lists.

The `@` operator is used to access named slots in an `S4` type object.

Comment: This worked nicely but what if I want to make a calculation (or say, set to zero) all the W1's without extracting them from the list?